# Replacing adjacent pixels with different colours

Tags: color, gimp

I have drawn an outline in a distinct colour and filled in everything I wanted. All that is left to do is to replace the outline inbetween and fill it with the adjacent colours. As there are many colours involved and it's not a continuous line of pixels, splitting it up and using the bucket tool is very time consuming.

So I want to know if there is a way to easily replace the lines with the adjacent colours. The program I used was GIMP, but if i.e. Photoshop can do this but GIMP can't, tell me anyway, so that I can do it in the other program.

[image: Example snippit]

Comment: Raster image editors like GIMP and Photoshop are not ideal for this kind of work. It would be much easier to create something like this using vector software such as Inkscape, or Adobe Illustrator.  Here's [a basic example](https://i.imgur.com/DKgBCCK.png) showing the steps in Inkscape, but the same is possible in Illustrator.  The benefit of using vectors is that the stroke can be removed in one step, also there are no horrible jagged pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make sure there is an alpha channel: `Layer > Transparency > Add alpha channel`
- Using the [Color selector](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-by-color-select.html) with a threshold set to `0`, select the red lines
- `Edit > Clear` or delete to remove the red lines and make them transparent
- `Filter > Blur > Median blur` and slowly increase radius until all the transparency is filled (you can hit Ctrl-T to hide the ants (but keep the selection active) while you do this.

[image]

This said, you probably used a sub-optimal technique initially, you are trying to fix a problem that can be avoided.

In Gimp, I would use the "Line art detection" potion of the bucket fill:

[image]

Tiny gaps can be fixed by a moderate median blur, or manually by painting in `Behind` mode (which will only paint transparent pixels)

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not know about the line art option so I will keep that in mind for future projects. As for using blur, I did try that with a brush before, but this works way better. Your answer will save me hours of work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest drawing it from the start so that there's no such big gap. The optimal way to work something like this is to draw the outline curves as paths in a vector drawing program. Use for ex. Inkscape.

In theory paths can be used also in GIMP, but Inkscape has superior tools for drawing and editing them. In GIMP paths can be used for making selections for color fills.

In the next image there'a at first drawn a rectangle. Then its area is divided with paths. Some of the paths are shaky freehand pencil tool strokes and there's also an ellipse and a nice smooth path drawn with the pen

[image]

All, but the rectangle are selected and combined to one path by applying Path > Combine. The result is lifted to the top in the layering order. Then the rectangle and and the combined path are selected and Path > Division is applied. The resulted group is ungrouped and all splinters are colored one by one by selecting for each a fill color:

[image]

The black lines vanish by selecting all and by removing the stroke color.

[image]

Every vector shape can be still edited, colored again and a stroke can be inserted, if needed.

The result is not perfect. When the image is rendered on the screen there's still a 2 screen pixels wide transition zone between the colors where the background color can be seen. It appears as well when you export the result as a bitmap file (I guess you want a PNG). The partially transparent gap does not harm if the PNG has higher resolution than the final watching resolution. Or you can place behind the vector shapes already in Inkscape something which has non-disturbing color.

Current version of Inkscape has Shape Builder which is very handy for defining the actual shape areas between crossing open and closed paths. It's in practice much more flexible than using path operations like Division.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the smooth curves aren't what I need though. The sample image is from a map layer for a game I am making a mod for and the game sadly works with these pixelated maps, so using paths would not work, thank you nonetheless.